# How can I use call by reference instead of call by value in this C program?

Tags: reference, call

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
float calc_celsius( float fahr, float *celc );
float calc_fahr( float celc, float *fahr );
float printAll(float f1, float f2, float f3, float c1, float c2, float c3); // last declaration

int main()
{

float c1, c2, c3, f1, f2, f3;

printf("Please type in three temperatures in fahrenheit \n");
scanf("%f %f %f", &f1, &f2, &f3);
printf("Please type in three temperatures in celsius \n");
scanf("%f %f %f", &c1, &c2, &c3);

printAll(&f1, &f2, &f3, &c1, &c2, c3);

return 0;

}

float calc_celsius( float fahr, float *celc )
{
*celc = (fahr - 32) * 5/9;
  return *celc;
}


float calc_fahr(float celc, float *fahr)

{

*fahr = (celc + 32) * 1.8;
return;
}

float printAll(float f1, float f2, float f3, float c1, float c2, float c3) {

printf("Fahrenheit \t | Celsius \n");
printf("***************************** \n");
printf("%.2f \t\t %.2f \n", f1, calc_celsius(&f1));
printf("%.2f \t\t %.2f \n", f2, calc_celsius(&f2));
printf("%.2f \t\t %.2f \n", f3, calc_celsius(&f3));

printf("The Temperature Conversions from Celsius to Fahreinheit are \n");
printf("Celsius \t | Fahrenheit \n");
printf("**************************** \n");
printf("%.2f \t\t %.2f \n", c1, calc_fahr(&c1));
printf("%.2f \t\t %.2f \n", c2, calc_fahr(&c2));
printf("%.2f \t\t %.2f \n", c3, calc_fahr(&c3));

}
```

So, I was just wondering, is it simple to just convert this program to using call by reference instead of value? I am having troubles, here is the code I have so far but im getting several errors that I don't understand.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
float calc_celsius( float fahr, float *celc );
float calc_fahr( float celc, float *fahr );
float printAll(float f1, float f2, float f3, float c1, float c2, float c3); // last declaration

int main()
{

float c1, c2, c3, f1, f2, f3;

printf("Please type in three temperatures in fahrenheit \n");
scanf("%f %f %f", &f1, &f2, &f3);
printf("Please type in three temperatures in celsius \n");
scanf("%f %f %f", &c1, &c2, &c3);

printAll(f1, f2, f3, c1, c2, c3);

return 0;

}

float calc_celsius( float fahr, float *celc )
{
*celc = (fahr - 32) * 5.0/9.0;
  return *celc;
}


float calc_fahr(float celc, float *fahr)

{

*fahr = (celc + 32) * 1.8;
return;
}

float printAll(float f1, float f2, float f3, float c1, float c2, float c3) {

printf("Fahrenheit \t | Celsius \n");
printf("***************************** \n");
printf("%.2f \t\t %.2f \n", f1, calc_celsius(&f1));
printf("%.2f \t\t %.2f \n", f2, calc_celsius(&f2));
printf("%.2f \t\t %.2f \n", f3, calc_celsius(&f3));

printf("The Temperature Conversions from Celsius to Fahreinheit are \n");
printf("Celsius \t | Fahrenheit \n");
printf("**************************** \n");
printf("%.2f \t\t %.2f \n", c1, calc_fahr(&c1));
printf("%.2f \t\t %.2f \n", c2, calc_fahr(&c2));
printf("%.2f \t\t %.2f \n", c3, calc_fahr(&c3));

}
```

And here are the errors I get when compiling:

```
\asn44.c||In function 'printAll':|
\asn44.c|42|error: incompatible type for argument 1 of 'calc_celsius'|
\asn44.c|23|note: expected 'float' but argument is of type 'float *'|
\asn44.c|42|error: too few arguments to function 'calc_celsius'|
\asn44.c|23|note: declared here|
\asn44.c|43|error: incompatible type for argument 1 of 'calc_celsius'|
\asn44.c|23|note: expected 'float' but argument is of type 'float *'|
\asn44.c|43|error: too few arguments to function 'calc_celsius'|
\asn44.c|23|note: declared here|
\asn44.c|44|error: incompatible type for argument 1 of 'calc_celsius'|
\asn44.c|23|note: expected 'float' but argument is of type 'float *'|
\asn44.c|44|error: too few arguments to function 'calc_celsius'|
\asn44.c|23|note: declared here|
\asn44.c|49|error: incompatible type for argument 1 of 'calc_fahr'|
\asn44.c|30|note: expected 'float' but argument is of type 'float *'|
\asn44.c|49|error: too few arguments to function 'calc_fahr'|
\asn44.c|30|note: declared here|
\asn44.c|50|error: incompatible type for argument 1 of 'calc_fahr'|
\asn44.c|30|note: expected 'float' but argument is of type 'float *'|
\asn44.c|50|error: too few arguments to function 'calc_fahr'|
\asn44.c|30|note: declared here|
\asn44.c|51|error: incompatible type for argument 1 of 'calc_fahr'|
\asn44.c|30|note: expected 'float' but argument is of type 'float *'|
\asn44.c|51|error: too few arguments to function 'calc_fahr'|
\asn44.c|30|note: declared here|
||=== Build failed: 12 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first program uses call by reference in a number of places, but also has many errors.

1) You use CBR incorrectly in your call to printAll. Specifically this line:

```
printAll(&f1, &f2, &f3, &c1, &c2, c3);
```

Uses CBR on all but the last argument. This is wrong, because *&f1* is a pointer to float, but printAll wants a float (and so for the other arguments).

2) printAll calls calc_celsius and calc_fahr with only one argument, but both functions expect two arguments.

3) You're passing the address of a float to calc_celsius and calc_fahr, but you should be passing the float itself.

4) calc_fahr is declared to return a float, but actually returns nothing.

5) Neither calc_celsius nor calc_fahr should need the second argument - just return the result of your expression (calculated from the first argument).

There are various things wrong with your second program too, but basically you just need to understand that &f means pointer-to-f. If your function expects a float, pass it one, don't pass pointer-to-float.

Answer (score 0):

You can stop wondering if it simple to just convert this program to using call by reference instead of value. It is simple and very elementary, as long as you understand why you are doing this conversion.

When you pass by value the called functions parameters are copies of the callers passed argument. Change the copy and the original argument does not change.

When you pass by reference the called functions parameters are the same variables as the callers passed argument, which means you do not pass just the value, but the variable itself. If the called function changes the parameter then the variable changes for the caller also. You do not just change the copy any-more but the real McCoy.

The signatures of your functions should be:

Pass by value (pass one value and the other is returned by the function to the caller)

```
float calc_celsius(float fahr);
float calc_fahr(float cels);
```

or

```
float calc_celsius(float);
float calc_fahr(float);
```

Pass by reference (pass one value and the second is modified by the function)

```
void calc_celsius(float fahr, float* cels);
void calc_fahr(float cels, float* fahr);
```

or

```
void calc_celsius(float, float*);
void calc_fahr(float, float*);
```

When you pass by reference you need a pointer to the actual variable which changes. This way you will not need to return any value to the caller.

The signature of printall is like this for both versions:

```
void printAll(float f1, float f2, float f3, float c1, float c2, float c3);
```

Your implemented functions should be:

Pass by value:

```
float calc_celsius(float fahr) {
    return (fahr - 32.) * 5. / 9.;
}

float calc_fahr(float cels) {
    return (cels * 1.8 + 32.);
}
```

And pass by reference:

```
void calc_celsius(float fahr, float* cels) {
    *cels = (fahr - 32.) * 5. / 9.;
}

void calc_fahr(float cels, float* fahr) {
    *fahr = (cels * 1.8 + 32.);
}
```

Finally the printAll, which has the same signature for both programs, should be like this for the pass by value value version:

```
void printAll(float f1, float f2, float f3, float c1, float c2, float c3) {

    printf("Fahrenheit \t | Celsius \n");
    printf("***************************** \n");
    printf("%.2f \t\t %.2f \n", f1, calc_celsius(f1));
    ...
```

And like this for the pass by reference version:

```
void printAll(float f1, float f2, float f3, float c1, float c2, float c3) {

    float cels, fahr;

    printf("Fahrenheit \t | Celsius \n");
    printf("***************************** \n");
    calc_celsius(f1, &cels);
    printf("%.2f \t\t %.2f \n", f1, cels);
    calc_celsius(f2, &cels);
    printf("%.2f \t\t %.2f \n", f2, cels);
    ...
```